# Lagom Framework - How to mix Java and Scala in the Same Service?

Tags: java, scala, microservices, spray, lagom

I am migrating from a [Spray Framework](http://spray.io/) (version 1.3.X) based JSON REST API service to a [Lagom Framework](https://www.lagomframework.com/) Service. Some developers are fluent in Scala and some are not and I just want to get it done with without having to force everyone to become fluent in Scala. How do I mix Java and Scala in the same Lagom Service?

Also, this is a bit of an aside, but can I do it with [Scala 2.13](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.13.0-M5.html) and [Java 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11)?